# Shopify Cart note not reliably submitting

Tags: forms, shopify, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

[image]

Hi!

I'm having an issue with a cart form submitting consistently.

Currently this is how [this page is code](https://haverford.com.au/cart).

1. I have a input box for customers to select their delivery notes (With a default option that writes to the Cart Note textbox).
2. This textbox is for customers so they can put in their own notes(optional).
3. There is a hidden textbox(css-display:none;) inside the form that has javascript to combine the options selected(from step 1 and 2) into the textbox.

Now the issue is it either submits the notes to shopify or the additional info but never both.
[image: notes to shopify]
[image: additional info to shopify]

```
<form data-cart-content="" data-cart-wrapper="" action="/cart" method="post" novalidate="" class="t4s-cartPage__form t4s-pr t4s-oh">
   <input
   id="delivery-leave"
   type="radio"
   name="attributes[Getting your delivery]"
   value="Leave in a safe place"
   >
   <select 
    id="choose-a-safe-location-to-leave-your-delivery" 
    name="attributes[Choose a safe location to leave your delivery.]"
   >
   <textarea 
    name="note" 
    id="CartSpecialInstructions" 
    class="t4s-cart-note__input" 
    placeholder="How can we help you?" spellcheck="false">
   </textarea>

   <textarea id="CartNote" placeholder="How can we help you?" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
</form>
```

I was expecting both the inputs and the cart note would submit to the order.

It only submits one or another, was there something I was missing? ie a shopify form submission limitation?

Comment: I think you missing the name attribute into last textarea, you need to check it with default one and correct it

Comment: @Onkar Thank you for checking the bug out. I removed the attribute from id="CartNote" so it didn't submit to Shopify. I was only needing the id="CartSpecialInstructions" to be recorded. The other inputs were purely to allow the script to compile them all together. Could this be the reason why it doesn't submit reliably? The form submitted sees all the fields without names & attributes so it chooses to submit nothing?